# how to remove unwanted box in ui-select?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ui-select

Using Angular and multi ui-select, the select box shows an unwanted "extra" box (see picture). How can I remove this?

[image]
Code:

```
      <ui-select multiple ng-model="definition.attachments" theme="bootstrap">
        <ui-select-match >{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="template.id as template in templates">{{template.name}}</ui-select-choices>
      </ui-select>
```

Comment: Inspect the elements class then add `display:none` in the css?

Comment: Can you give me the plunkker code?

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely caused by failing to include the `select.css` file in your `index.html` file. Add the following to your `<head>` tag in your `index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/select.css"/>
```

Comment: i have been searching for days....the missing stylesheet was the reason. You conquered my heart...